# How to change the axis on this ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

My bifurcation diagram almost works, but I can't figure out how to replace the point number on the horizontal axis with the x coordinate from my calculation.  I have tried a whole bunch of things that fail in various ways.  The code is below.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: bifurcation]

```
z[0, c_] := c;
z[n_, c_] := z[n - 1, c]^2 + c;
zSeries[n_, len_, c_] := Module[{ser},
   ser = {z[n, c]};
   Do[AppendTo[ser, ser[[i]]^2 + c], {i, 1, len - 1}];
   ser];
ListPlot[Transpose[Table[zSeries[999, 100, x], {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]]
```

If I change the zSeries module to give each point its own x value, it gets VERY slow.

```
zSeries[n_, len_, c_] := Module[{ser},
   ser = {{c, z[n, c]}};
   Do[AppendTo[ser, {c, ser[[i]]^2 + c}], {i, 1, len - 1}];
   ser];
```

Comment: Try the `DataRange` option in `ListPlot`.

Comment: Jerry, as bb says, you adjust `DataRange` so that the horizontal axis is in the right units. Look at the docs for it. BTW, `NestList[]` is pretty useful for implementing your `zSeries`.

Comment: Since the $x$-coordinate is fixed, you could just do something like `{c, #} & /@ ser` after generating them like in your original version.

Comment: @J.M.  Yes, that's better coding, thank you.  The lingering problem I have now is how much it slows down, but that might not be solvable.

Comment: Do you realize that `Do[AppendTo[res, f[x]], {x, n}]` is the same as `res = Table[f[x], {x, n}]`, only 100 times slower (ignoring the time to compute `f[x]`)?

Comment: @Jerry, as I said, consider using `NestList[]`; repeated use of `AppendTo[]` is well-known to be a slow way of accumulating results.

Comment: @J.M.  Ah!  I was only using AppendTo[] because I didn't know about NestList[].  NestList[] does exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: This was a hugely helpful discussion.  I had to learn 3 new Mathematica tricks to make this work, but I got it.  I put all these helpful comments into the solution I posted as a second Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate my comment, is that what you had in mind?

```
ListPlot[Transpose[Table[zSeries[999, 100, x], {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], DataRange -> {-2, .25}]
```

[image]

**Addendum: Timing**

The OP in his answer provides revised code,

```
z[0, c_] := c;
z[n_, c_] := z[n - 1, c]^2 + c;
ListPlot[Catenate[Table[{x, #} & /@ NestList[#^2 + x &, z[999, x], 100], 
    {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]]
```

which is much faster than the earlier code, requiring `64 sec` (`AbsoluteTiming`) on my PC to generate the plot.  Still, it seemed to me that further improvements in time could be achieved.  `Table` requires `37 sec` to generate the array, leaving `27 sec` for `ListPlot` itself.  Because as many as `100` duplicate points are plotted for `x > -1.4`, applying `DeleteDuplicates` offers an obvious savings.  (It, like `Catenate`, takes negligible time.)  Using `FixedPointList` instead of `NestList` also saves a bit of time for `x > -.76`, but only a few seconds, because the reduced list generation is largely offset by the test for a fixed point.  Together,

```
ListPlot[Catenate[Table[{x, #} & /@ DeleteDuplicates[
   FixedPointList[#^2 + x &, z[999, x], 100]], {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], PlotRange -> All]
```

requires only about `41 sec`.  The other opportunity for savings involves replacing `z[999, x]`, which takes some `31 sec` in all, by the equivalent `Nest[#^2 + x &, x, 999]`,

```
ListPlot[Catenate[Table[{x, #} & /@ DeleteDuplicates[
    FixedPointList[#^2 + x &, Evaluate[Nest[#^2 + x &, x, 999]], 100]], 
    {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], PlotRange -> All]
```

which reduces total time to `11 sec`, a significant improvement.  (Using `FixedPoint` instead of `Nest` offers no further advantage.)

Comment: It gets the job done in this case, because my x's happen to be evenly spaced.  It's not really directly using my x coordinate.  If my x's weren't evenly spaced, this wouldn't work.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not the spacing being used here @Jerry; the horizontal axis is merely being scaled so that the left and right extents of the plot correspond to what's on your data.

Comment: I think I need to associate an x-value with each set of points calculated from that x.

Comment: @JerryGuern  For non-uniformly spaced points, give `ListPlot` arrays of `{x, y}` values.  (I see that you just suggested that yourself, and it should  work.)  I see no other way to plot randomly spaced points.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  That was among the things I couldn't figure out how to make work.  I have 100 y's associated with each x.

Comment: @JerryGuern  Give each one its own `x` value.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  I tried that just now and got it to work, but for some reason it is extremely slow.  I put the code I used to add the x's in the Question.  It works now, but the slowness is puzzling and displeasing.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Well anyway, you answered my question.  Thank you!

Comment: I learned from this other [Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107661/why-is-listplot-so-slow-for-coordinate-pairs-can-we-speed-it-up) that it was plotting slowly (and colorfully) because I had  list-of-lists of pairs, and each list of pairs was getting styled differently.  Using Catenate[] reduced the list-of-lists to a list.
ListPlot[Catenate[Table[{x, #} & /@ NestList[#^2 + x &, z[999, x], 100], {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]]

Comment: @JerryGuern  I  have been able to reduce runtime by a factor of about six, as shown in the addition to my answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Thanks for follow-up.  I've learned at least 5 new Mathematica commands from this discussion.  I'm surprised that my recursive z[999,x] was so inefficient, but it looks like replacing that with Nest was the biggest speed gain.  This has me thinking about other efficiencies now, since 999 and 100 are obviously just convenient large numbers.  999 lets the z[_,x] series get nearly asymptotic, and 100 is usually redundant but necessary at chaotic points.

Comment: @JerryGuern  I too found this problem instructive.  Your definition of `z` follows standard procedure, but in retrospect was consuming a lot of time.  I shall consider that when I define similar functions.  `Cantenate` was new to me, although it is not that different from `Flatten`.  With my changes, the majority of the time now goes to `ListPlot` itself, so I think that the only way to save much more time is to plot fewer points.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

From the OP:  Based on the helpful Comments and Answer above, here's all I needed to do to get the plot I wanted:

```
z[0, c_] := c;
z[n_, c_] := z[n - 1, c]^2 + c;
ListPlot[Catenate[Table[{x, #} & /@ NestList[#^2 + x &, z[999, x], 100], {x, -2, .25, .0001}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]]
```