# Why is ListPlot[] so slow for coordinate pairs? Can we speed it up?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I compared the time it took to create a plot in two different ways.  I expected the first method to be slower, but I was surprised at how much.  Is this an inherent limitation or the function, or are there options I could use to speed up the plotting in cases where I need to actually use coordinate pairs?
[image: compare]

```
z[0, c_] := c;
z[n_, c_] := z[n - 1, c]^2 + c;
Timing[a = Table[{x, #} & /@ NestList[#^2 + x &, z[999, x], 100], {x, -2, .25, .001}];]
Timing[ListPlot[a]]
Timing[b = Flatten[Table[NestList[#^2 + x &, z[999, x], 100], {x, -2, .25, .001}]];]
Timing[ListPlot[b]]
```

The first method creates `{x,y}` pairs, while the second just creates `y's`.  The plots look the same because the `x's` happen to be evenly spaced and in order, and because the horizontal offset between points that correspond to the same `x` is too small to see.

Comment: I don't have access to older versions, but apparently one way to speed it up would be to [use version 7](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84739/9490)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's not entirely true:

```
a // Dimensions
```

> {2251, 101, 2}

So it's a 2d array of paris, and each row is treated as separate set to plot, `ListPlot` is trying to style them differently, etc. That's what takes time probably.

You can keep pairs and do a fast plot reducing it to simple list of pairs. With `Flatten[#,1]` or `Catenate`:

```
ListPlot[
  a
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[
  Catenate @ a
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer.  I miss the pretty colors but enjoy the 20x speed up.

Answer (score 7):

[Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) has already given a good answer, I just want to mention, if *generating* speed is concerned:

```
Graphics[{ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[1]], Point@Flatten[a, 1]}, Axes -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

But sadly the *displaying* speed of the above result seems to be slower than that of `ListPlot`. See the comments below for more information.

Comment: It seems that `ListPlot` is optimized for displaying and `Graphics` for generating. I tried with `Graphics` too but a problem is that `AbsoluteTiming` is unreliable. Try setting `t = AbsoluteTime[];` before that code and print `AbsoluteTime[]-t` after. It's about 50% longer than `ListPlot` solution, and not even close to what `AbsoluteTiming` says. On the other hand, if you just want to generate it and save, `Graphics`  is better.

Comment: I believe part of the overhead is due to the fact that `ListPlot[]` is trying to do a lot of "smart" things behind the scenes (e.g. the plot theme), so if one is fine with a plain display, using `Graphics[]` with primitives is very attractive.

Comment: @Kuba Yeah, I noticed it just now, too. Quite surprising I should say, I thought `ListPlot` is just a `Graphics` generator!

Comment: When I ask a question and it touches off a discussion among experts that's completely over my head, I feel a brief and probably undeserved sense of accomplishment.

Comment: I think it just needs a ``Developer`ToPackedArray[Flatten[a,1]] `` to make it render as fast as `ListPlot` (have not really measured that...), so it might be that use of packed arrays is all the "hidden" optimization that `ListPlot` does...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Your guess is right, at least according to the `AbsoluteTime[]-t` measurement, but this leads to another problem, that is, the `AbsoluteTime[]-t` measurement seems to be inaccurate, too, if my sense of time is correct! (Maybe I should pinch a stopwatch?)

Comment: @xzczd: measuring such timings when two communicating processes work together is a science in itself. For all practical purposes I think getting the right order of magnitude with `AbsoluteTime[]` measurements for a piece of code running at least in the order of one second and trying to keep the machine free of other load is usually good enough. If you need more, it gets difficult...