# How to approximate the solution of a system of quartic equations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, difference-equations

In an attempt to evaluate the point at which the cycle 2 becomes unstable for the given map:

\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}=μ-x_n^4=f(x_n), \quad μ \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

I have so far managed to locate the two numerical values $\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2$ for which the period 2 trajectory appears:

```
Manipulate[Module[{list = NestList[μ - #^4 &, x0, 100]}, list2 = list;
Column[{ListLinePlot[list, PlotRange -> {-1, 1.5}, 
ImageSize -> {450, 375}], 
TableForm[Transpose@{Range[86, 101], list[[-16 ;;]]}, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"point", "x"}}]}]], {{μ, 0.2, 
"parameter μ"}, 0, 4, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{x0, 0.4, 
"Initial \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)"}, 0, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

But now I would like to locate the value of $μ$ for which this 2-cycle ceases to be stable and jumps onto the next one, a 4-cycle. The condition which has to hold is the following:
\begin{equation}
f'(\hat{x}_1)f'(\hat{x}_2)=-1 \Leftrightarrow 16\hat{x}_1^3 \hat{x_2}^3=-1
\end{equation}
where $\hat{x}_i,i=1,2$ would be an expression of $μ$.

The problem is that *Mathematica* is not able to solve analytically the system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} f(\hat{x}_1)=\hat{x}_2 \\ f(\hat{x}_2)=\hat{x}_1 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
in order to get the trajectory of the 2-cycle in a closed form, which will depend only on the parameter $μ$, which I can then plug it in the condition and find the value of that $μ$. What I get instead for

```
Reduce[{y == μ - z^4, z == μ - y^4}, {y, z}, Reals]
```

is the solution in Root form:

```
 ((μ == Root[27 + 256 #1^3 &, 1] && 
 y == Root[-μ + #1 + #1^4 &, 1]) || (Root[27 + 256 #1^3 &, 1] < 
 μ <= Root[-125 + 256 #1^3 &, 
 1] && (y == Root[-μ + #1 + #1^4 &, 1] || 
 y == Root[-μ + #1 + #1^4 &, 2])) || (μ > 
 Root[-125 + 256 #1^3 &, 1] && (y == Root[-μ + #1 + #1^4 &, 1] ||
 y == Root[
 1 - μ^3 - μ^2 #1 - μ #1^2 - #1^3 + 3 μ^2 #1^4 + 
 2 μ #1^5 + #1^6 - 3 μ #1^8 - #1^9 + #1^12 &, 1] || 
 y == Root[-μ + #1 + #1^4 &, 2] || 
 y == Root[
 1 - μ^3 - μ^2 #1 - μ #1^2 - #1^3 + 3 μ^2 #1^4 + 
 2 μ #1^5 + #1^6 - 3 μ #1^8 - #1^9 + #1^12 &, 2]))) && 
 z == -y^4 + μ
```

I understand that I am not able to solve this system analytically, but how can I then approximate this particular $μ$ value.

If I plug in the condition above the numerical values of $\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2$, I would have no $μ$ involved.

The point of this whole procedure is to calculate somewhow the universal $\delta$ *Feigenbaum* constant for this representative of the quartic equivalence class of discrete mappings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Replace the `=` with `==` in your `Reduce` and also check documentation for those respective symbols.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Thank you, you were right. But still, how can I then plug in those non-analytical roots into the condition mentioned above? Sorry for my perhaps naive questions I am still new to Mathematica, trying my best to make decent questions here.

Comment: `p = Reduce[{y == \[Mu] - z^4, z == \[Mu] - y^4}, {y, z, \[Mu]}, Reals,
     Backsubstitution -> True] // FullSimplify // N; First@p`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Thank you for your help! But I cannot understand fully what did you do there. Mathematica returned to me the value $μ=6.29$. Is that the $μ$ which I would get if I knew the exact expression of $\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2$ and solved for $μ$ the condition: $ 16 {\hat{x}_1}^3{\hat{x}_2}^3=-1$ ?

Comment: @Mitscaype `8. \[Mu] == 6.29961`, actually

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Excuse me for asking this but how to translate      8. \[Mu] == 6.29961    from Mathematica? Whats does the "eight dot \mu" means? Again sorry for this question but I am really new at this one.

Comment: @Mitscaype `p = Reduce[{y == \[Mu] - z^4, z == \[Mu] - y^4}, {y, z, \[Mu]}, Reals,
     Backsubstitution -> True] // FullSimplify // N; Solve[p[[1]]]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Ok, now I see. So this is the $μ$ for which I get the solution of the system above. Can I do the same for a 4x4 system, which represents a 4-cycle, to see when does it happen?

Comment: @Mitscaype Not sure, I haven't followed your math, just  tried to help with that Reduce

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Ok then! Thanks a ton, you really did help :)

Comment: Maybe a more informative title would be "How to find bifurcation points in a quartic map"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with a brute-force bifurcation diagram to see what's happening, modifying some code from @bbgodfrey's answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107731/how-to-create-a-version-of-fixedpointlist-for-asymptotically-periodic-functions/107736):

```
f[x_, μ_] := μ - x^4;

res[μ_] := 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   NestList[f[#, μ] &, Nest[f[#, μ] &, μ, 1000], 100], 
   Round[#, 10^-6] &];

ListPlot[Catenate[Table[{μ, #} & /@ res[μ], {μ, 0, 1.2, 0.001}]], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Looks like the `μ` you're looking for is near 1.1.  To find a 2-cycle for a given `μ` numerically, we can try

```
μ = 1.05;
FindRoot[f[f[x, μ], μ] == x, {x, -0.5}]

(* {x -> -0.162297} *)
```

The bifurcation occurs when the two-cycle goes through a period-doubling bifurcation (eigenvalue=-1).  We can numerically find the the bifurcation point by simultaneously solving for the two-cycle and when it loses stability:

```
Clear[μ];
FindRoot[{f[f[x, μ], μ] == x, D[f[f[x,μ], μ], x] == -1}, {x, -0.5}, {μ, 1.1}]

(* {x -> -0.359832, μ -> 1.11964} *)
```

Edit:

To generalize to higher order cycles (e.g. here's where the 4-cycle gives way to an 8-cycle):

```
FindRoot[{Nest[f[#, μ] &, x, 4] == x, D[Nest[f[#, μ] &, x, 4], x] == -1}, 
    {x, -0.64}, {μ, 1.16}]

(* {x -> -0.646515, μ -> 1.16166} *)
```

Of course it gets more delicate, so you'll probably want better initial guesses (which I got from looking at a zoomed-in version of the bifurcation diagram).

I don't know of any way to directly calculate the Feigenbaum constant here.

Edit 2:

I applied this approach to the first 7 period-doublings.  The ratio of bifurcation points as in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants) looks like `{7.90629, 7.25658, 7.3238, 7.28859, 7.28785}`.

Comment: Actually that is pretty correct. I was guessing the bifurcation values of $μ$ from a $x_{n+1}$ vs $n$ plot and I was around 1.13 for a 4-cycle. But to locate the 8-cycle is pretty hard this way. Is there also a code for the Feigenbaum $\delta$ in this case?

Comment: I edited my answer to give code to generalize to finding the bifurcation of an `n`-cycle.  I also tried calculating that δ for you: looks like around 7.288 if I didn't mess that up.

Comment: Found [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079009-6/S0025-5718-1991-1079009-6.pdf) which says it's 7.28468..., which makes me feel OK.

Comment: Well, I guess I will have to thank like, forever! Yeah, I was able to approximate that $\delta$ too, but only by the first 2 iterations. I was around 8.28, which means wayyyyy out when it comes to this kind of systems. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Not a bad paper either. I guess I had missed that somehow. Again, thanks