# Calculating the Feigenbaum Constants

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, iterators

I would like to calculate the $δ$ and the $α$ Feigenbaum constants for the Logistic Map:

\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}=4μx_n(1-x_n)=f(x_n)
\end{equation}
as part of an undergraduate assigment of mine. I have managed so far to calculate explicitly the 2-cycle and the value of $\mu$ for which it becomes unstable, leading to the bifurcation of the 4-cycle.
My attempt of calculating the $δ$, which is defined as 
\begin{equation}
δ=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{μ_{n}-μ_{n+1}}{μ_{n+1}-μ_{n+2}}
\end{equation}
is given below

```
f[x_Real, mu_Real, n_Real] := Block[{y = x}, Do[y = 4 mu y (1 - y), {n}]; y]
mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^2] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
delta[n_] := (mu[n - 1] - mu[n - 2])/(mu[n] - mu[n - 1])
mu[n_] := mu[n] == mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^n] == 
1/2, {mu, {mu[n - 1] + (mu[n - 1] - mu[n - 2])/delta[n - 1], 
mu[n - 1] + (mu[n - 1] - mu[n - 2])/(delta[n - 1] + .01)}}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 10]
Table[mu[n], {n, 0, 7}]
Table[delta[n], {n, 2, 7}]
```

I am literally a rookie in the *Mathematica* software and tbh I have searched online a lot in order to write this piece of code above. Anyway, I am getting an error of the form

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
```

once I try to calculate the various values of the $μ$-cycles. *(for example: mu[3])*.

I would really appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Seems like you are putting "x=0.5" as your starting point, right?

Comment: @MathX That is correct yes.

Comment: your function  for `mu[n]` is recursive, but you didnt define the base case `mu[1]` anywhere.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform But how should that be done. Is it a particular command to be used here or I just define what    mu[1]     should be? Also, shouldn't that be a result of the function? When I start iterating it should calculate, among the rest, also    mu[1]    right? Sorry, but as I stated above I am all new to this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Spy93 I cannot help you further because I dont know anything about the Feigenbaum Constants. About your code I can say: the definition of `mu[n]` includes `mu[n-1]`. This means that if you ask Mathematica  to calculate `mu[10]`, the result will depend on `mu[9]` which Mathematica doesnt know its value. Therefore, it will compute `mu[9]` to get the value, but this depends on `mu[8]` which Mathematica doesnt know its value - **ad infinitum**. If at the begining of your code you include `mu[1]=1` (for example), then the process ends when the recursion hits the base case `mu[1]` (hope this helps)

Comment: Check out [this recent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109691/how-to-approximate-the-solution-of-a-system-of-quartic-equations) for a related problem.

Comment: What exactly does `FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^2] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]` do here, and why's this the right thing to do?  (It seems that it is, but I can't see why).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several changes are required to obtain the desired results.  First, the syntax error `mu[n] == mu` must be replaced by `mu[n] = mu`.  Next, initial conditions must be provided for the recurrence in `n`:

```
mu[0] := mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^0] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
mu[1] := mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^1] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
mu[2] := mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^2] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
```

However, even with these changes, `FindRoot` in lines 4 - 6 of the code in the question does not evaluate `mu[n - 1]`, etc in the initial guesses for its search.  This issue can be circumvented by moving the evaluation of these quantities outside `FindRoot`.  Altogether, the revised code becomes

```
f[x_Real, mu_Real, n_Real] := Block[{y = x}, Do[y = 4 mu y (1 - y), n]; y]
mu[0] := mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^0] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
mu[1] := mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^1] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
mu[2] := mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^2] == 1/2, {mu, 0.9}]
delta[n_] := (mu[n - 1] - mu[n - 2])/(mu[n] - mu[n - 1])
mu[n_] := mu[n] = Module[{mu1 = mu[n - 1] + (mu[n - 1] - mu[n - 2])/delta[n - 1], 
    mu2 = mu[n - 1] + (mu[n - 1] - mu[n - 2])/(delta[n - 1] + .01)}, 
    mu /. FindRoot[f[1/2, mu, 2^n] == 1/2,  {mu, mu1, mu2}, AccuracyGoal -> 10]]
Table[mu[n], {n, 0, 7}]
Table[delta[n], {n, 2, 7}]

(* {0.5, 0.809017, 0.87464, 0.88866, 0.891667, 0.892311, 0.892449, 0.892478} *)
(* {4.70894, 4.68077, 4.66296, 4.6684, 4.66895, 4.66916} *)
```

Comment: How does `f[1/2, mu 2^n]` even evaluate, since `1/2` and `2^n` aren't `Real`?  When I run `f[1/2, 0.7, 2]` it doesn't evaluate, yet these `FindRoot`s work.

Comment: @ChrisK   Interesting observation.  Perhaps, `FindRoot` passes real numbers.  In any case, the `Real` conditions can be eliminated, if `Evaluated -> False` is added to the `FindRoot` call.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you very much  for your answer. It was really helpful!